# @staff_member_required is throwing "object has no attribute 'user'"

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using this decorator to make this page staff-only:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @staff_member_required
    def dostuff(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("This is secret")

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r"^dostuff/$", self.dostuff)
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

But for some reason I'm getting:

`AttributeError: 'MyModelAdmin' object has no attribute 'user'`

Without the decorator, the view works fine (but anyone can see it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`method_decorator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.method_decorator):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dostuff(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("This is secret")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Reading through the docs for an explanation I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#id1): `A method on a class isn’t quite the same as a standalone function, so you can’t just apply a function decorator to the method – you need to transform it into a method decorator first.`